# Compiler error when creating a KeyBoard Hook

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am introducing myself to using Hooks in Win32 C++ (specifically KeyboardHooks) & I have an issue & a question.

First off, I am trying to just create/declare a HHook object, but when I do Microsoft Visual C++ gives a compiler error saying:

```
c:\users\soribo\desktop\c++ programming\visual c++ programming\testhhook\testhhook\testhhook.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'keyboardHook'

1>c:\users\soribo\desktop\c++ programming\visual c++ programming\testhhook\testhhook\testhhook.cpp(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\users\soribo\desktop\c++ programming\visual c++ programming\testhhook\testhhook\testhhook.cpp(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

This is the line of code that generates this error:

```
HHook keyboardHook;
```

What windows library do I need to include to use the HHook class? I have done

```
#include <windows.h>
```

My other question is, to use these hooks do I need UAC?

**EDIT: With more code:**

```
// TestHHook.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

     #include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestHHook.h"

static HHook keyboardHook;
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

Comment: are you defining a struct or class just before that line? does it have the required `;` at the end of its definition?

Comment: No the only lines before that are #include's. I think I that I may not be including the correct library to use this object. All I include is windows.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a case sensitive language.  It is HHOOK, not HHook.